# JavaFx getSelectedRow and GetSelectedItem from TableView and get the value of the columns in separate variabls

Tags: java, javafx-2, tableview

i am using Javafx with SceneBuilder i wanted to know how we can get the items or the values of a selected row in a Table View whene we click a button ( in my case Edit Button hwo display the separate data in Text field in an other window to edit it and save it ) 
i have for columns ( id , name, surname, age ) object Student .
here is my the action of the button

```
try {                   
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Ajout.fxml").openStream());
    AjoutController ajoutcontroller = (AjoutController)loader.getController();

    // recupérer men la table les elements hna  we n7otohom fe nameR we surnameR we ageR
    table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
    nameR = table.getItems(); // from the table view element in column name to the variable nameR 

    ajoutcontroller.GetStudentDetail(nameR, surnameR, ageR);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage primaryStage= new Stage();
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
} catch(IOException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one hwo needs it

```
 Student stud = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    String nameR = stud.getName();
    String surnameR = stud.getSurname();
    String ageR = stud.getAge().toString();
```

and in the other scene where the Taxt Fields are you juste put this function

```
 public void GetStudentDetail(String nameR, String surnameR, String ageR){

    nametf.setText(nameR);
    surnametf.setText(surnameR);
    agetf.setText(ageR);
    btnajout.setText("Save");
```

}